# How can a shiny app recognize when a complete word has been typed into a text input?

Tags: r, shiny

In [Shiny](http://shiny.rstudio.com), text input can be provided by the user. When a user is typing, I want to executed server side code, but only once a complete word has been typed. Can I execute whenever "space" is entered?

Comment: I know this doesn't directly answer your question --- because I don't know the answer --- but what about using `submitButton()`?

Comment: It should work "continuously" while the user is typing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know any packages that would actually check for the entire word. As you can imagine other languages probably will need to be included in there too. Given an example with an activation if a string has a space you can do the following: Note that the space doesn't have to be after something is typed and will activate if there are any spaces in the string. To include more test cases I suggest you play around with `regexpr`, `library(stringr)`, `library(stringi)`. Have a look [R Programming/Text Processing](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/R_Programming/Text_Processing) for some examples

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)

ui =(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Words With Spaces"),
  sidebarPanel(
    textInput("my_text", "Type something (will activate if has space):", "")),
  mainPanel(textOutput("text"))
))

server = function(input, output, session){

  output$text <- renderText({

    if(is.na(is.null(input$my_text)) || is.null(input$my_text)){return()}

    if(regexpr(" ",input$my_text)[1] > 0){input$my_text}
  })  
}
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I'm looking for for the moment. Good starting point. And english only is alright for the moment.